# Custom react hook with useState always resetting to its initial value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

I am trying to create a custom react hook for saving the state of 9 elements in an object with either true or false.

```
let pads = {
  Q: false,
  W: false,
  E: false,
  A: false,
  S: false,
  D: false,
  F: false,
  Z: false,
  X: false,
  C: false,
};

export default () => {
  const [padsPlaying, setPadsPlaying] = useState(pads);
  return {
    padsPlaying,
    setPlayState: (element, state) => {
      setPadsPlaying({ ...state, [element]: true });
    },
  };
};
```

In my component i import the hook and call it like that:

```
  const { padsPlaying, setPlayState } = usePlayState();

  const playSound = (element) => {
   
 // do some other stuff and in the end:

    setPlayState(element.id, padsPlaying);
  };
```

It works, an element.id of `Q`returns the state with `Q:true`and everything else `false`. However, if I run the function again it resets `Q`to its initial value of `false` and the new element is `true`. Can someone point me in the right direction? I tried different combinations of setting the play state and initialising the state but I feel I'm just shooting in the blue, what am I missing here?

EDIT: I am using that state to render a list of components with a prop of isPlaying to be either `true`or `false`

```
  const makePads = preset[0].sounds.map((sound, i) => (
    <DrumPad
      key={sound.id}
      id={sound.name}
      name={sound.name}
      source={sound.source}
      trigger={sound.trigger}
      isPlaying={padsPlaying[i]}
    />
  ));
```

SOLVED
I got confused as where I was using the old state, now the hook looks like this and it is working :)

```
export default () => {
  const [padsPlaying, setPadsPlaying] = useState(initialPads);
  const setPlayState = (id) => {
    setPadsPlaying((state) => {
      console.log(id);
      return { ...state, [id]: true };
    });
  };
  return [padsPlaying, setPlayState];
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are accessing the state incorrectly but I'm not sure because you didn't all code to see how you are accessing the state.

I recreated a little example from your code

```js
let pads = {
  Q: false,
  W: false,
};

const usePlayState = () => {
  const [padsPlaying, setPadsPlaying] = useState(pads);

  const setPlayState = (element, state) => {
    setPadsPlaying({ ...state, [element]: true });
  }

  return [
    padsPlaying,
    setPlayState,
  ];
};


function Testme() {

  const [padsPlaying, setPlayState] = usePlayState();


  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(padsPlaying) // the proper way to access the new updated state is here
  })

  return (<div>

    <button onClick={() => {
      setPlayState('Q', padsPlaying);
      // console.log(padsPlaying); // => Q still false because you still have the old stale state
    }}>
      Q
    </button>

    <button onClick={() => {
      setPlayState('W', padsPlaying);
      // console.log(padsPlaying); // => W still false because you still have the old stale state
    }}>
      W
    </button>

  </div>)
}
```

and I pointed you where is the proper way to access the new state which is in `useEffect` which is more equivalent `ComponentDidMount`, if you are accessing the state immediately you will get the old `state` and you will find that `Q` still false while reading the value from inside `useEffect` will give the new real value

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply, I edited my original question so you can see where I access that state.